# Jquery Ajax refresh not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a `<ul>` which refreshes every ten seconds to check if there have been any new tweets (its pulling from a twitter feed). This works fine in Firefox and Chrome etc, but it does not work in any version if Internet Explorer.

My code is as follows:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#banter .scroll-pane").load(location.href+" #banter .scroll-pane>*","");
}, 10000);
```

My PHP function creating the list is as follows:

```
function showTweets($section, $limit, $class) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hash WHERE section = '".$section."' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ".$limit);

    echo '<ul class="scroll-pane '.$class.'">';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<li>';
                echo '<p>'.html_entity_decode($row['tweet']).'</p>';
                echo '<a href="'.$row['user_url'].'">'.$row['user'].'</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Any idea what's going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Can you alert(location.href); and receive the current URL?

Comment: Yep, I can alert that and it alerts the correct URL in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix it, turns out it was a caching issue with IE.  So to fix it I put a unique query containing the unix time on the end of the call to the PHP file. For example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#banter .scroll-pane").load('test.php'+"?ms=" + new Date().getTime());
}, 6000);
```

Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) of .load() states this about loading page fragments:

> Note that the document retrieved cannot be a full HTML document; that is, it cannot include (for example) `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. jQuery uses the browser's innerHTML property on a   element to parse the document, and most browsers will not allow non-body elements to be parsed in this way.

This is probably the problem here - since you're loading `location.href`, I assume you're getting back a full HTML document. Creating a PHP page that retrieves only the relevant part of the HTML should fix this.

Comment: Hi, I tried this, I put my function in a PHP file and called that instead, and it still doesn't update in IE.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is already answer, but if someone read that question today or after, I think the problem resides on the cache, IE will have in cache the response of the page therefore it will not ask again for it.

Add the following line on the server side to prevent it.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
```